# Web site which allows users to provide feedback/rate web site design variations

Tags: website-design

I've come up with several mockups for a design refresh of one of my existing sites, but I'm having a hard time selecting a design.

Is there any web site which allows to submit a number of designs and allow it's users to rate those designs?

Comment: Ask on webapps.stackexchange.com or doctype.com.

Comment: This would be a great stackoverflow site, or you should start one. I'd help :) In fact SO-UX should add a feature for that.

Comment: http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1745147 I haven't tried this yet but it looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

[Forrst](http://forrst.com/) might be a good place to get some feedback (although there isn't a voting mechanism other than "likes").

Comment: Thanks for the Forrst link. Unfortunately it's currently invite only so it might be a while until I get my invite.

Comment: I applied on the site and got membership within two days. (Unfortunately, I don't have an invites left. Otherwise, I would invite you.)

Comment: "Like" would not be suffiecent. Would need more details as to why you gave it that rating. A lot like product ratings.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered running some A/B testing and actually trying out the designs on some real users to see if they work better?

Comment: Once I've narrow down the design I plan on doing just that but for now, I need to get feedback about several mockups I have to narrow them down to just one or two. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: totally agree here. Which design concept a user likes better is a very different question to which user experience is most effective.  I would argue your approach might even be a little dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Sign up for Deviantart.com and join lots of the web and interface groups, post your images on your folio page then submit them to each of the groups you have joined. It's worth a shot.

Comment: This would be the best option since DA has a large community behind it and is well known. However, still no rating system like he would need

Comment: Damn, yep no rating system. There are favs but not really a rating as such. There is http://designerscouch.org/ but what they call a rating is pretty much just favs.

Answer (score 1):

[Conceptfeedback](http://www.Conceptfeedback.com) sounds like it would be the best option for you. There are a lot of experts on there that really give you in depth analysis and it is a great community.

Answer (score 1):

[Usara](http://usaura.com/) sounds like exactly what you want, it's simple, it's free, and it has no barrier for entry for your users.
Here's an [example test](http://www.usaura.com/test/4c3012474ee090a51273) you can take right away:

[image]

You share a link to your test and collect data on your "dashboard" right away, for this sample test you'll see the count and % of what users picked which item.

They also have heatmap style tests:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've tested out https://usabilityhub.com/ Worked fine for me! quick usability tests. Maybe a bit small, but simple to use;
I will start using Usabilityhub.com on more frequently bases now; due to low cost and i except a lot of results.

I think i will use mostly the clicktest for simple/small tasks. For example: you set a task "Where would you click first" together with a wireframe/screenshot.

You can chose to run a test public or private (invite people by e-mail). If you participate in public tests, you can run free tests (public or private) in return.